# Exporting python data to elasticsearch

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I have the following dataframe :

```
date_facture product_description  ...     nouv2    ecartt
0   2020/04/01 00:01:14                 xyz  ...  1.00  0.00
1   2020/04/01 00:02:29                None  ...  2.00  1.00
2   2020/04/01 00:03:14                  eu  ...  1.00  0.00
3   2020/04/01 00:04:17                 com  ...  1.00  0.00
```

I would like to export it to elasticsearch and for that I need to transform it into the appropriate format.

For the moment my code is :

```
es_url_rw = url_elastic
es_index_rw = 't_angelique'

def json_converter(o):
if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
    return o.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

print(requests.put(es_url_rw + es_index_rw).text)

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}.

data = df.to_json()

bulk_json = []
bulk_json.append(json.dumps({'index': {'_index': es_index_rw, '_id': 123}}})))
bulk_json.append(json.dumps(data, default=json_converter))


requests.put(es_url_rw + '_bulk', data='\n'.join(bulk_json) + '\n', headers=headers)
```

But in doing so I can't find the data on elastic. I know that the problem comes from this line:

```
data = df.to_json()
```

Indeed, I first tested

```
data=df.to.dict()
```

with all the orient parameters possible, I found the data on elastic but they were not in the right format. And when I test with :

```
data=df.to_json()
```

I don't even find the data on elasctic.
I really don't know what to do now. Could you help me please ?

Comment: Yes, but in this case the data does not appear on elastic :/

Comment: Also you are missing the '_source' field which will have the data in  this line bulk_json.append(json.dumps({'index': {'_index': es_index_rw, '_id': 123}}})))